# Broken script fails to break calling program

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, popen

What specific syntax needs to be changed in the code below in order to cause the broken script to halt the program that calls it?

**PROBLEM:**

An object-oriented Python 3 program needs to run external scripts.  The problem is that, when the program calls a script that breaks, the Python program just continues running instead of halting with an error message.

The scripts are provided by third parties we do not control, so that the object-oriented Python 3 program needs to do the error handling when a called script breaks, and we cannot control the content of the called scripts.

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM:**

1. Create two directories and place the following 4 files in the 2 directories.  One directory named MyApp, and the other directory named AnotherDir.  The file structure should look like:

   ```
    AnotherDir\scripts\brokenScript.py
    MyApp\app\main.py
    MyApp\app\second_level.py
    MyApp\app\third_level.py
   ```
2. Navigate the command line to the parent directory of AnotherDir and MyApp
3. Run the following command to reproduce the problem:

   ```
    python MyApp\app\main.py
   ```

We are developing this on Windows, but it is intended to be OS-agnostic.

**PROBLEM RESULT:**

The problem is that the results look like:

```
About to run a broken script that should break on error.
command is:  python C:\path\to\AnotherDir\scripts\brokenScript.py
shell Inside broken script.  The script should break on the next line.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
FAILED TO THROW ERROR. Done running the broken script, but it returned without breaking this calling program.  This print command should never run if the script breaks.  Instead, a graceful error message should terminate the program.
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

The brokenScript.py script's non-zero exit code should cause the calling program to halt instead of continuing to run.

**CODE TO REPRODUCE THE PROBLEM:**

100% of the bare minimum code to reproduce this error is as follows:

`AnotherDir\scripts\brokenScript.py` contains:

```
import sys

print("Inside broken script.  The script should break on the next line. ")
sys.exit(1)
```

`MyApp\main.py` contains:

```
from second_level import second_level
import sys

def runCommands():
  wfsys = second_level()
  wfsys.offFoundation()
  print("--------------------------------------")
  sys.exit(0)

runCommands()
```

`MyApp\second_level.py` contains:

```
from third_level import third_level

class second_level:

  def __init__(self):  
    pass

  def offFoundation(self):
    tl = third_level()
    print("About to run a broken script that should break on error.")
    callScript = "\\AnotherDir\\scripts\\brokenScript.py"
    tl.runScript(callScript)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("FAILED TO THROW ERROR. Done running the broken script, but it returned without breaking this calling program.  This print command should never run if the script breaks.  Instead, a graceful error message should terminate the program.")
```

`MyApp\third_level.py` contains:

```
import subprocess
import re
import sys 
import os
import platform

class third_level:

  def __init__(self):  
    pass
 
  ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

  def runShellCommand(self, commandToRun):
    proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      if line:
        thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
        decodedline=self.ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
        logString = decodedline
        print("shell", logString)
      else:
        break

  def runScript(self, relativePathToScript):
    userCallingDir = str(os.path.abspath("."))+'\\'
    userCallingDir = self.formatPathForOS(userCallingDir)
    fullyQualifiedPathToScript = userCallingDir+relativePathToScript
    fullyQualifiedPathToScript = self.formatPathForOS(fullyQualifiedPathToScript)
    if os.path.isfile(fullyQualifiedPathToScript):
      commandToRun = "python "+fullyQualifiedPathToScript
      print("command is: ",commandToRun)
      self.runShellCommand(commandToRun)
    else: 
      logString = "ERROR: "+fullyQualifiedPathToScript+" is not a valid path. "
      print('shell', logString)
      sys.exit(1)

  def formatPathForOS(self, input):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
      input = input.replace('/','\\')   
    else:
      input = input.replace('\\','/')  
      input = input.replace('//','/')
    if input.endswith('/n'):  
      input = input[:-2] + '\n'
    return input
```

Comment: Capture the exit status of the external script, and if it is nonzero, handle it however you like.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Use `subprocess.check_call()` or `subprocess.check_output()`. These will automatically raise an exception if the subprocess exits with a non-zero status code.

Comment: @Barmar See the answer I posted below for how I got this to work.  Your approach might have worked, but your approach would have required refactoring all our subprocess-related code.

Answer (score 0):

For the code given in the OP, the solution was to add the following three lines:

```
stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
  print("ERR4R: The script that was called returned a non-zero return code: ", proc.returncode)
```

The complete code for the function those three lines were added to then becomes as follows:

```
def runShellCommand(self, commandToRun):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  stdoutdata, stderrdata = proc.communicate()
  if proc.returncode != 0:
    print("ERR4R: The script that was called returned a non-zero return code: ", proc.returncode)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
      decodedline=self.ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
      logString = decodedline
      print("shell", logString)
    else:
      break
```

Everything else in the OP can remain the same and the entire program will work as expected.